# Drag and drop listeners and handlers not working [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

So I'm trying to implement basic drag and drop in java using the javafx library. setOnDragDetected is working fine but the Pane I'm dragging element into isn't responding to any of the drop events.

[image]
*"Actual image of the problem the pane to be dragged into is in blue, the elements to be dragged are the rectangles."*

I have looked at different tutorials and articles and their source code didn't help either.
Tried with and without lambdas.

The code used on the Pane to be dragged

```
public abstract class VueEtapeIG extends Pane {
       public VueEtapeIG(...){
            //some code..
            this.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            //activate();
            Dragboard db = this.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            // Store node ID in order to know what is dragged.
            content.putString(this.getId());
            db.setContent(content);
            System.out.println("setOnDragDetected");
            event.consume();
        });
    }
}
```

The code used on the Pane to be dragged into :

```
public class VueDessin extends Pane implements Observer
{
     public VueDessin(...){
        //some code..
        setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != this && 
                      event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                System.out.println("acceptTransferModes");
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
            System.out.println("setOnDragOver");
            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            System.out.println("Dropped!");
            // Get item id here, which was stored when the drag started.
            boolean success = false;
            // If this is a meaningful drop...
            if (db.hasString()) {
                String nodeId = db.getString();
                //Search for the etape dropped
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        });
    }
}
```

I expect the print statements in these even listener to work and then i can implement further other features, but at the moment it seems that listeners and handlers aren't even working

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."

Comment: I guess I clarified everything

Comment: Solved : content.putString(this.getId()); the problem in this line getId is sometimes returning a null and thus the listener isnt working while putString is waiting for a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt find any noticible errors with your code. So unable to point exact issue. May be if you try with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you may come to know. Please check the below demo of what I tried and it is working well. Try to figure out what is going wrong with your code (in comparision to this).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class DragDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        VBox imageBox = new VBox();
        Node node1 = buildNode("red");
        Node node2 = buildNode("yellow");
        imageBox.getChildren().addAll(node1,node2);

        StackPane displayBox = new StackPane();
        displayBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;");
        HBox.setHgrow(displayBox,Priority.ALWAYS);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(imageBox,displayBox);
        root.getChildren().add(hb);

        displayBox.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != displayBox &&
                    event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        displayBox.setOnDragEntered(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != displayBox && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                displayBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-opacity:.4;-fx-background-color:"+event.getDragboard().getString());
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        displayBox.setOnDragExited(event -> {
            if(!event.isAccepted()) {
                displayBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;");
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        displayBox.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                displayBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-background-color: "+db.getString());
                success = true;
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        });

    }
    private Node buildNode(String color){
        StackPane node = new StackPane();
        node.setPrefSize(200,200);
        node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+color);
        node.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            Dragboard db = node.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putImage(node.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(),null));
            content.putString(color);
            db.setContent(content);
            event.consume();
        });
        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: content.putString(this.getId()); the problem in this line getId is sometimes returning a null and thus the listener isnt working while putString is waiting for a string

Comment: Have you verified that your VueEtapeIG will always contains an id.

Comment: No thats why it didn't work :) the id java is returning is null sometimes I discovered that when i looked at the source code of getId() therefor the problem.Thanks for helping .